# VB.NET - OleDbException saying Spreadsheet is full when inserting to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, oledb

I have a VB.Net program that reads in a flat file, and then parses line by line, formatting the data into different spreadsheets in an excel workbook (each line can be any 10+ different record types so I parse and put in appropriate excel sheet).

For smaller sized flat files (under 10mb), the parser works great.  However, I am trying this on a file that is over 120mb (400k+ lines).  While running, I will get an OleDBException saying that the spreadsheet is full.  Now I am pretty confident that Excel can handle a much larger data set than a flat file.  So I assume this exception is not giving me the true story as to what is really occuring.

I open a connection, and then parse each line in the file, inserting each row into the excel file.  I assumed it would be bad performance wise to open/close the connection between each insert.  Could this be causing the issue?  Any ideas what I need to do to handle such a large file?  There are cases where the flat file can be over 500mb.

To actually do the insert into excel, I am just doing the following (I construct an sql query based on the type of row and values parsed):
`Dim conn As New OleDbConnection()`
`conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ExportLocation.Text + "\" + importFileName + "-PVF.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"""`
`conn.Open()`

`Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand()`
`cmd1.Connection = conn`
...parser code...
`cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + rowType + " values (" + currentRowString + ")"`
`cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: What version of Excel are you writing to?

Comment: Sorry, I was still adding the bits of code.  I never even thought about that, but according to the connection string, looks to be Excel 8.0?  I copied the connection stream and modified it, but I would like it to work on most recent versions.  If I'm not mistaken, 8.0 would be 97 correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel 8.0 is the same as Excel 97 which allows a maximum of 65,536 rows.  You're exceeding this.

Comment: Oh wow, you are right.  I guess I will have to make it the minimum of 2007 then.  Thanks for that!